# oracle table insert transaction log

Tags: oracle, logging, insert

I have an application that is built on top of a framework; the framework handles all the communication and requests to/from the DB. I have Oracle 12c.

The application is an electronic document management system; I have one document when trying to commit it will generate an error, the error is not that self-explanatory as begin controlled by the framework, the error related to the DB commit process.
I tried to check the constraint/Index for that specific table related to the eDoc with no luck.

How I can get more log from oracle itself when inserting the data, hoping I can get a better idea of why the error is happening.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a test database that you can reproduce the error in, you can create an `AFTER SERVERERROR` trigger to log any errors that occur.

If you try this in production, you risk large-scale problems for all users and applications accessing the database, especially if you make a mistake.  **Doing this in a dev/QA instance is strongly recommended!**

Here is a short example of how to do that:

```
-- Create a table to hold the error log
CREATE TABLE matt1_errors (
    error_ts        TIMESTAMP,
    stacktrace      VARCHAR2(4000),
    sql_stmt        VARCHAR2(4000)); 
/

-- Create a trigger to log any server errors that occur
CREATE TRIGGER matt_log_errors AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  l_sql_pieces_list DBMS_STANDARD.ora_name_list_t;
  piece_count PLS_INTEGER;
  l_sql_text VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  piece_count := ora_sql_txt(l_sql_pieces_list);

  FOR i IN 1..piece_count LOOP
    l_sql_text := substr(l_sql_text || l_sql_pieces_list(i), 1, 4000);
  END LOOP;

  INSERT INTO matt1_errors ( error_ts, stacktrace, sql_stmt)
     VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP, dbms_utility.format_error_stack, l_sql_text);

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
END;
```

#### Test it...

```
-- Create a table to insert into.
CREATE TABLE matt1 ( id NUMBER, text VARCHAR2(4) );
-- Cause an error.
insert into matt1 (id, text) VALUES (1, 'Too long!!!');

-- See what we got...
select * from matt1_errors;


+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|            ERROR_TS             |                                      STACKTRACE                                      |                        SQL_STMT                        |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 06-NOV-19 03.02.18.083116000 PM | ORA-12899: value too large for column "APPS"."MATT1"."TEXT" (actual: 11, maximum: 4) | insert into matt1 (id, text) VALUES (1, 'Too long!!!') |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

So,

1. Create the `AFTER SERVERERRORS` trigger
2. Reproduce your error
3. Check the table that your trigger writes to